# RichText :inserthtml not working properly in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, rich-text-editor, execcommand

I am trying to insert some text content at the cursor position in my contentEditable iframe
for the following content(`<span style='fontweight:bold'>ab</span>`)
ab... Here i place the cursor after ab and if if i execute the following command
`document.execCommand('insertHTML',false,"c")`
The resulting html is as follows
`<span style='fontweight:bold'>ab</span>c`

What i required is 
`<span style='fontweight:bold'>abc</span>`

Note: This issue is only in Firefox, In chrome and safari i get the expected behavior which is needed for me.

Please suggest a way to get this behavior in FF

Comment: did you solved this issue ?